# Error in installing NS2

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ns2

[image]
Here is the Error i am getting while installing NS2 in version 2.35 in ubuntu 14.04. 
What is the solution of the error ?

Do I need to re-install the whole setup or specific module because this error happen after some time.

I have tried 2 time and both time got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in `ns-2.35/linkstate/ls.h` and in the line 137 replace the :

```
void eraseAll() { erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

whith :

```
void eraseAll() { baseMap::erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
$ sudo apt-get install ns2  nam xgraph

Also this reference can be used to install ns2

https://getch.wordpress.com/tag/sudo-apt-get-install-ns-nam-xgraph/